# How can I get the folder level for a publishing page

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, folder, breadcrumb

I am using SP2013 standard on-premise. On a site collection publishing infrastructure is activated. Under "Pages" library nested folder structure is add and multiple aspx files are stored.

We applied nested folder approach because we need to setup permission for different folder/subfolder level.

The problem is I want to display a breadcrumb view on the pages. Hence page viewers (the users) can see which level the page is located. For example, if user browse the page at

> http://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/pages/level1/level2/test.aspx

, the breadcrumb should show

> Root > level1 > level2 > test.aspx

However, all the pages (*.aspx) do not have a querystring **RootFolder**. How can I get this piece of information?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no method for this. You will have go back using `SPFolder.ParentFolder` until you hit the root folder or it may be easier to parse the URI and take the next URI part after the list as the root folder and work your way down.